# how to filter with mulitple data based on condition in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to filter based on the value coming from the jason .how to filter more than one value.here is my code.

```
<div  ng-click="mailType('All')">All</div>
    <div ng-click="mailType('Messages')"> Messages</div>
    <div ng-click="mailType('Referrals')">Referrals</div>

    <div  ng-repeat="email in inboxEmailList() | filter:{status: 'new'}">       
            <div>{{email.Date}}</div>       
            <div>{{email.type}}:{{email.subject}}</div>
            <div>{{email.Time}}</div>
            <div>{{email.from}}</div>       
    </div>
```

here inboxEmaillist is having json data with fileds (date,type,time,from,status[new,deleted,sent],type[Message,Referral]).when I click 'all' it should show both message and referral and when i click message it should show message type .how do I add this filter along with the existing filter(status:new)?

Answer (score 0):

You can chain filters, like so:

```
<div  ng-repeat="email in inboxEmailList() | filter:{status: 'new'} | filter:typeToFilter">
```

You can also set `typeToFilter` directly  within your `ng-click`.

```
<div ng-click="typeToFilter = {}">All</div>
<div ng-click="typeToFilter = {type: 'Messages'}"> Messages</div>
<div ng-click="typeToFilter = {type: 'Referrals'}">Referrals</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response and it resolved my issue. it is working good. many many thanks.

Comment: is there any tag in angular js to highlight the tab when we click on the item.in my example when i click on all it should higlight .how to do this with angular tags?